# Setting CATALINA_OPTS for tomcat6 on windows doesn't work

Tags: jmx, tomcat6

I'm trying to setup Tomcat6 to work with JMX on Windows Vista 64.

To do that I need to pass the parameters below to Tomcat6.

What I do in command prompt. (that doesn't work)

```
set CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9898 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
tomcat6.exe
```

What I do that does work (but causes other problems)

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9898 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -jar bootstrap.jar
```

It seems as if tomcat is just ignoring the environment variable CATALINA_OPTS.
Am I doing something wrong?

--- Update - Since writing this i've tried to edit catalina.bat and define the variable CATALINA_OPTS there. No success. (tried adding the parameters to JAVA_OPTS too, no success either)

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but might this get a better reply at "serverfault"?

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of that website, i'll try there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I started tomcat with tomcat6.exe instead of startup.bat.

Now works.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the possibility that TC6 could be broken in that environment as I can't check it myself, there are a couple of things you can check:

- You have two - characters in your CATALINA_OPTS line in the first parameter, should be one. That would break it, I expect.

If not that:

- Is anything else in your Tomcat startup script overwriting CATALINA_OPTS?

Comment: Thanks. The double - chars were a typo for the web site.
The actual command was run without the typo.